# VK api wall.post

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Есть `standalone` приложение в вк. Загрузка и сохранение фотографий проходит успешно. Но как только после этого хочу запостить фото через аттач `wall.post` приход  json з ошибкой

> Access denied to call this method. В wall.post (scope (wall,group,photos,offline))

Передаю свежеиспеченный токен, `owner_id`, `message attachments`. Буду рад за подсказку.

Comment: метка `php` в вашем вопросе говорит о том, что у вас НЕ standalone приложение...... ибо standalone это десктоп или мобильные,.... а значит и доступ к методам у вас оправданно закрыт....... а чтобы опубликовать на стену - нужно пользоваться как раз таки standalone или  ClientAPI, OpenAPI и SDK у которых будет отображаться окно подтверждения поста на стену, в котором данный метод нуждается ...... https://new.vk.com/dev/api_confirm